# Swapping Image Source on Hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a section on my page, where I am swapping the image source of a specific image when I hover over that section's links.  This is working very well for the most part.  If I hover over a link, and then go out the transition happens exactly as I want.  If I hover over a link, and then proceed to the next link without letting the image swap back to the original, the transition is abrupt and not what I want.

My question is, how do I transition cleanly from link to link? I can't assume that the user will always hover over one and then back out before going to the next.

My HTML:

```
<div class="home-intro-pic">
  <img class="lazy practice-area-img" data-src="wp-content/uploads/2021/08/auto-accidents.jpg" alt="Auto Accidents Lawyer">
  <img class="practice-area-img-hover" alt="Auto Accidents Lawyer"/>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.home .legal-matter .home-intro-pic img {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
 .home .legal-matter .home-intro-pic img.practice-area-img {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .home .legal-matter .home-intro-pic img.practice-area-img.hovered {
     opacity: 0;
}
 .home .legal-matter .home-intro-pic img.practice-area-img-hover {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .home .legal-matter .home-intro-pic img.practice-area-img-hover.hovered {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

The jQuery

```
 jQuery("#practices-menu li a").hover(function(){
        var pa_img = jQuery(this).data('image');
        jQuery(".practice-area-img-hover").attr("src", pa_img);
        jQuery(".practice-area-img-hover").toggleClass("hovered");
        jQuery(".practice-area-img").toggleClass("hovered");
      });
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is no animation because the source change. One idea could be to not change the source but clone the image, change the source of the newly created image, trigger the animation once the file as been downloaded and delete the "original" image

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you're looking for but what about if you would add a few px of margin between your links. Then the pointer will "leave" one link before hovering over the next one.

Comment: They already do. I mean I guess maybe I'm moving too quickly between them while testing.